# Spring Boot testing: Cannot bind @ConfigurationProperties - Ensure that @ConstructorBinding has not been applied

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, junit5

In a Spring Boot unit test, how can you mock @ConstructorBinding @ConfigurationProperties data class?

#### Setup

- Both

  - Kotlin 1.4.30 (for unit tests and config classes)
  - Java 15 (with --enable-preview) (for business logic)
- Spring Boot 2.4.2
- Junit 5.7.1
- Mockito (mockito-inline) 3.7.7
- Maven 3.6.3_1

I want to test FtpService (a `@Service`, which has a `RestTemplate`) with different configurations.

Properties for the FtpService come from a Kotlin data class - UrlProperties - which is annotated with `ConstructorBinding` and `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Note: FtpService's constructor extracts a property from UrlProperties. This means that UrlProperties must be both mocked **and** stubbed **before** Spring loads FtpService

#### Error

When I try and mock UrlProperties so that I can set the properties for different tests, I either receive an error, or am unable to insert the bean

```
Cannot bind @ConfigurationProperties for bean 'urlProperties'. Ensure that @ConstructorBinding has not been applied to regular bean
```

---

#### Code

`@SpringBootTest` of FtpService | `src/test/kotlin/com/example/FtpServiceTest.kt`

```java
import com.example.service.FtpService
import com.example.service.UrlProperties
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.mockito.Mockito.`when`
import org.mockito.Mockito.mock
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.AutoConfigureWebClient
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration


@TestConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = [FtpService::class])
@AutoConfigureWebClient(registerRestTemplate = true)
class FtpServiceTest
@Autowired constructor(
    private val ftpService: FtpService
) {

  // MockBean inserted into Spring Context too late,
  // FtpService constructor throws NPE
//  @MockBean
//  lateinit var urlProperties: UrlProperties

  @ContextConfiguration
  class MyTestContext {

    // error -
    // > Cannot bind @ConfigurationProperties for bean 'urlProperties'.
    // > Ensure that @ConstructorBinding has not been applied to regular bean
    var urlProperties: UrlProperties = mock(UrlProperties::class.java)

    @Bean
    fun urlProperties() = urlProperties

    // error -
    // > Cannot bind @ConfigurationProperties for bean 'urlProperties'.
    // > Ensure that @ConstructorBinding has not been applied to regular bean
//    @Bean
//    fun urlProperties(): UrlProperties {
//      return UrlProperties(
//          UrlProperties.FtpProperties(
//              url = "ftp://localhost:21"
//          ))
//    }
  }

  @Test
  fun `test fetch file root`() {

    `when`(MyTestContext().urlProperties.ftp)
        .thenReturn(UrlProperties.FtpProperties(
            url = "ftp://localhost:21"
        ))

    assertEquals("I'm fetching a file from ftp://localhost:21!",
        ftpService.fetchFile())
  }

  @Test
  fun `test fetch file folder`() {

    `when`(MyTestContext().urlProperties.ftp)
        .thenReturn(UrlProperties.FtpProperties(
            url = "ftp://localhost:21/user/folder"
        ))

    assertEquals("I'm fetching a file from ftp://localhost:21/user/folder!",
        ftpService.fetchFile())
  }
}
```

#### Workaround - manual definition every test

The only 'workaround' is to manually define all beans (which means I miss out on Spring Boot magic during testing) and in my view is more confusing.

Workaround - manual redefinition each test | `src/test/kotlin/com/example/FtpServiceTest2.kt`

```java
import com.example.service.FtpService
import com.example.service.UrlProperties
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.mockito.Mockito.`when`
import org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn
import org.mockito.Mockito.mock
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder


class FtpServiceTest2 {

  private val restTemplate =
      RestTemplateBuilder()
          .build()

  private lateinit var ftpService: FtpService

  private lateinit var urlProperties: UrlProperties

  @BeforeEach
  fun beforeEachTest() {
    urlProperties = mock(UrlProperties::class.java)

    `when`(urlProperties.ftp)
        .thenReturn(UrlProperties.FtpProperties(
            url = "default"
        ))

    ftpService = FtpService(restTemplate, urlProperties)
  }


  /** this is the only test that allows me to redefine 'url' */
  @Test
  fun `test fetch file folder - redefine`() {

    urlProperties = mock(UrlProperties::class.java)
    `when`(urlProperties.ftp)
        .thenReturn(UrlProperties.FtpProperties(
            url = "ftp://localhost:21/redefine"
        ))
    // redefine the service
    ftpService = FtpService(restTemplate, urlProperties)

    assertEquals("I'm fetching a file from ftp://localhost:21/redefine!",
        ftpService.fetchFile())
  }
  
  
  @Test
  fun `test default`() {
    assertEquals("I'm fetching a file from default!",
        ftpService.fetchFile())
  }

  @Test
  fun `test fetch file root`() {

    `when`(urlProperties.ftp)
        .thenReturn(UrlProperties.FtpProperties(
            url = "ftp://localhost:21"
        ))

    assertEquals("I'm fetching a file from ftp://localhost:21!",
        ftpService.fetchFile())
  }

  @Test
  fun `test fetch file folder`() {

    doReturn(
        UrlProperties.FtpProperties(
            url = "ftp://localhost:21/user/folder"
        )).`when`(urlProperties).ftp

    assertEquals("I'm fetching a file from ftp://localhost:21/user/folder!",
        ftpService.fetchFile())
  }

  @Test
  fun `test fetch file folder - reset`() {

    Mockito.reset(urlProperties)
    `when`(urlProperties.ftp)
        .thenReturn(UrlProperties.FtpProperties(
            url = "ftp://localhost:21/mockito/reset/when"
        ))

    assertEquals("I'm fetching a file from ftp://localhost:21/mockito/reset/when!",
        ftpService.fetchFile())
  }

  @Test
  fun `test fetch file folder - reset & doReturn`() {

    Mockito.reset(urlProperties)
    doReturn(
        UrlProperties.FtpProperties(
            url = "ftp://localhost:21/reset/doReturn"
        )).`when`(urlProperties).ftp

    assertEquals("I'm fetching a file from ftp://localhost:21/reset/doReturn!",
        ftpService.fetchFile())
  }
}
```

Spring App | `src/main/kotlin/com/example/MyApp.kt`

```java
package com.example

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesScan
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
class MyApp

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  runApplication<MyApp>(*args)
}
```

Example @Service | `src/main/kotlin/com/example/service/FtpService.kt`

```java
package com.example.service

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate

@Service
class FtpService(
    val restTemplate: RestTemplate,
    urlProperties: UrlProperties,
    val ftpProperties: UrlProperties.FtpProperties = urlProperties.ftp
) {

  fun fetchFile(): String {
    println(restTemplate)
    return "I'm fetching a file from ${ftpProperties.url}!"
  }
}
```

@ConfigurationProperties with @ConstructorBinding -  `src/main/kotlin/com/example/service/UrlProperties.kt`

```
package com.example.service

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConstructorBinding

@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("url")
data class UrlProperties(val ftp: FtpProperties) {

  data class FtpProperties(
      val url: String,
  )
}
```

Comment: I think that inside `UrlProperties.kt`, adding `@get:Bean` to `val ftp: FtpProperties ` might be a solution. Then it's a bean that can be mocked, and also it prevents NPEs in the service constructor.

Comment: Have you found any solution ? I'm facing the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

You can provide a custom configuration using the `@TestPropertySource` annotation and provide different configurations. A similar result can be achieved by providing the properties in the `@SpringBootTest` annotation. You won't create your custom  URL properties bean then.

See also: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-tests-override-properties

This approach is potentially expensive as your Spring context will be rebuilt for every test class that has this annotation + the following test, which can add multiple seconds to your overall test runtime.

## Option 2

You can mock just your configuration bean using `@MockkBean` (from https://github.com/Ninja-Squad/springmockk) and specify the return values. This differs from your workaround as you still have a full Spring context and just one mock.

Example:

```kotlin
@TestConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = [FtpService::class])
@AutoConfigureWebClient(registerRestTemplate = true)
class FtpServiceTest {

  @Autowired
  private lateinit var ftpService: FtpService
  
  @MockkBean
  private lateinit var urlProperties: UrlProperties

  @Nested
  inner class `scenario 1` {

     @BeforeEach
     fun setup() {
         every { urlProperties.ftp } returns "url for scenario 1"
     }
  }

  @Nested
  inner class `scenario 2` {

     @BeforeEach
     fun setup() {
         every { urlProperties.ftp } returns "url for scenario 2"
     }
  }
}
```

Using mocks in spring also has a performance impact while this one would be smaller than the one in option 1.

## Option 3

As you are only testing the FTP service itself, you can also just instantiate again within a spring test. So for your test, you create a dedicated instance which uses all beans + your custom properties.

Example:

```kotlin
@TestConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = [FtpService::class])
@AutoConfigureWebClient(registerRestTemplate = true)
class FtpServiceTest {

  // example for a bean from the context you want to inject but not define yourself
  @Autowired
  private lateinit var otherBean: OtherBean

  @Nested
  inner class `scenario 1` {

     private val urlProperties = UrlProperties(ftp = "url for scenario 1")
     private val ftpService = FtpService(urlProperties, otherBean)

  }

  @Nested
  inner class `scenario 2` {

     private val urlProperties = UrlProperties(ftp = "url for scenario 2")
     private val ftpService = FtpService(urlProperties, otherBean)
  }
}
```

This would be the fastest approach - and combined with Spring test slices, you might speed it up even more. But it would not test the actual wired service.

## Alternative

I'm not sure whether it is feasible for your use case: you can also mock your FTP server (there are some ready-to-use ones available) and providing different responses during each test run. This would allow you to test the bean built by spring and you might be able to get around spring context rebuilds, thus having a pretty fast test.